# Removing the underline from under a visited link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, visited

What is the CSS code that I need to write in order to remove the underline from these link after visiting them?

```
<ul id = "header">
    <li><a href="sigur ros.html"> Home </a> </li>
    <li>Images</li>
    <li>Videos</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
```

but it didn't work.

Here is a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/litari/X2Yjk/1/

Comment: Then are you sure it's on visited?

Comment: I assume that if the URL is invalid, the page probably won't be remembered as visited by the browser

Comment: yes, the non visited ones are still blue. and the visited one is purple.

Comment: What you tried is in fact the correct way to do it, so there's probably another issue. As @ex0ns suggested, your URL might be invalid (since there's a space in the name).

Comment: I changed the url and removed the spaces, the issue is still there.

Comment: I think he said everything: 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4910041/1062711

Comment: a:visited, a:focus { text-decoration: none; }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't change text-decoration in :visited

Rather set text-decoration:none on anchors and text-decoration:underline on links you want underlined. For example you can use a class to achieve this.

```
a
{
   text-decoration:none;
}

a.underlined
{
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: While this appears to be the case (you can't change it), can you link a source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471929/underlining-visited-links

Comment: in this case, shouldnt i apply the .underline class only to the visited links?

Comment: No. If you set text-decoration:none to all links none of them will be underline unless specified with a class.

Comment: oh okay. i understood it the other way around for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should define the default state as well, so for example:

```
a:link { text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: I tried this too, but it also didn't work.

Comment: @joe11093 Just a question, did you try to add it in a style tag, like this? <style type="text/css"> a:link { text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }</style> -- this should be posted in the head section of the html page.

Comment: yes. all the css i wrote for this one is written in the head of the html page.

Answer (score 0):

If existing code is not working for you then please add "!important" in your property.

```
a:visited
{ 
     text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try

```
outline: 0;
```

It might work on FF.

Comment: this one didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, changing `text-decoration` for `:visited` anchors does not work.
But you could do the following:

```
a {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited { 
    border-bottom-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

This works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/N8c3A/
To test it using chrome inspect the anchor with the developer tools, rightclick the markup and say "Force element state" -> ":visited".